# Debian and TI usb3410

Tags: debian, usb

I have a TI usb3410 usb device (it is a TI MSP-FET430UIF programmer), when connected to my debian machine (running squeeze 2.6.32-5-amd64) it shows up in dmesg as

```
[ 3159.380099] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=f430
[ 3159.380108] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3159.380116] usb 2-1: Product: MSP-FET430UIF JTAG Tool
[ 3159.380121] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Texas Instruments
[ 3159.380128] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: TUSB3410410886330C60FFD9
[ 3159.380411] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[ 3159.384312] ti_usb_3410_5052 2-1:1.0: TI USB 3410 1 port adapter converter detected
[ 3159.384336] usb 2-1: firmware: requesting ti_usb-v0451-pf430.fw
[ 3159.391011] usb 2-1: firmware: requesting ti_3410.fw
[ 3159.399203] usb 2-1: ti_download_firmware - firmware not found
[ 3159.399240] ti_usb_3410_5052: probe of 2-1:1.0 failed with error -5
```

and lsusb as

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0451:f430 Texas Instruments, Inc. MSP-FET430UIF JTAG Tool
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:010c Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

However, there is no corresponding device in /dev (it is supposed to show up as /dev/ttyUSB0 etc.)

I have tried creating a udev rule (as described in http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/mspgcc/index.php?title=Getting_Started_with_Debugging), but that made no difference. In that page (and also http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=979460) it is suggested to copy (or link) the firmware to a new location - but on my system, the firmware does not exist in the original location (which makes copying / linking it kinda hard).

I have installed the firmware packages (firmware-linux-nonfree, firmware-linux-free and firmware-linux) but it still does not exist.

/lib/firmware looks like

```
3com              cxgb3                     hp           mts_gsm.fw
advansys          dabusb                    kaweth       r128
agere_ap_fw.bin   dsp56k                    keyspan_pda  radeon
agere_sta_fw.bin  dvb-fe-xc5000-1.6.114.fw  matrox       tehuti
av7110            dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw   mts_cdma.fw  tigon
cis               e100                      mts_edge.fw
```

So my question is, what do I have to do to make this usb device work / where can I find the firmware files?

Comment: Have you tried locating the firmware file to make sure it isn't present? `sudo updatedb && locate ti_3410.fw`

Comment: I've just tried it and it returns "/dev/.udev/firmware-missing/ti_3410.fw" which is a zero size file

Comment: Looks like you'll need to build & install the firmware yourself: http://packages.debian.org/search?arch=amd64&searchon=contents&keywords=ti_3410.fw

Comment: The only downside is that I don't know where to find its sourcecode. The impression I got from the above links is that it is included with most distributions.

Comment: There is an rpm here: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=firmware(ti_3410.fw)

Comment: That's brilliant - downloaded the rpm, unpacked it (google helped) and copied the firmware across and now it shows up in /dev. I do wonder why debian doesn't include the firmware files though (I presume licensing issues).

Comment: Cool. Write up what you did as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the suggestion from jasonwryan, I downloaded the rpm from [here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=firmware%28ti_3410.fw%29) which is a package containing firmware for OpenSuSE 11.2.

I then extracted the rpm (using `rpm2cpio kernel-firmware-20090821-4.1.noarch.rpm |cpio -vid`). This creates two directories, lib and usr. The firmware is in the lib directory, so copying to the system was simply `sudo cp lib/firmware/ti_* /lib/firmware/`. This copies over the two firmware files (ti_3410.fw and ti_5052.fw). Then, after plugging in the device, it showed up in the dev folder as ttyUSB0 (like it should).

I still don't know why these files are not included (or available as a debian package), I can only imagine it is because of debian's licensing requirements.